# Busybox Recursive Non-Overwriting File Copy?

Tags: linux, busybox

How do I do a recursive file copy to copy any missing files without overwriting? (Busybox `cp` has no `-n` option and no `rsync`.)

The line below would be fine if the overwrite `n` response was automatically entered. Also need to exclude a couple of specific directories.

```
#!/bin/sh
target="/www/docroot/"
source="/rom$target"
cp -ir "$source"* "$target"
```

Comment: Is it for a real system or a Docker container?

Comment: You could try installing a standalone version of the cp program to replace the Busybox applet.

Comment: @xenoid - real system in Technicolor modem. sawdust - prefer not as installation script for public use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/19997505/3092763

```
false | cp -ir source destination 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Note comment from @mginius re ARG_MAX files.